# mutual recursion on an inductive type and nat

Tags: recursion, coq, termination

Consider this example:

```
Inductive T :=
| foo : T
| bar : nat -> T -> T.

Fixpoint evalT (t:T) {struct t} : nat :=
  match t with
  | foo => 1
  | bar n x => evalBar x n
  end
with evalBar (x:T) (n:nat) {struct n} : nat :=
  match n with
  | O => 0
  | S n' => (evalT x) + (evalBar x n')
  end.
```

Coq rejects it with an error: *Recursive call to evalBar has principal argument equal to "n" instead of "x"*.

I understand that termination checker got confused by two unrelated inductive types (T and nat). However, it looks like the function I am trying to define will indeed terminate. How can I make Coq accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to use a nested fixpoint.

```
Fixpoint evalT (t:T) {struct t} : nat :=
  match t with
  | foo => 1
  | bar n x => let fix evalBar n {struct n} :=
                 match n with
                 | 0 => 0
                 | S n' => Nat.add (evalT x) (evalBar n')
                 end
               in evalBar n
  end.
```

The important point is to remove the argument `x` from `evalBar`. Thus the recursive call to `evalT` is done on the `x` from `bar n x`, not the `x` given as an argument to `evalBar`, and thus the termination checker can validate the definition of `evalT`.

This is the same idea that makes the version with `nat_rec` proposed in another answer work.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found is to use `nat_rec` instead of `evalBar`:

```
Fixpoint evalT (t:T) {struct t} : nat :=
  match t with
  | foo => 1
  | bar n x => @nat_rec _ 0 (fun n' t' => (evalT x) + t') n
  end.
```

It works but I wish I could hide `nat_rec` under `evalBar` definition to hide details. In my real project, such construct is used several times.